# Cloud Composer missing variables file

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I've been trying to import a JSON file of environment variables to a newly created Cloud Composer instance using the [airflow CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#variables) but when running the below I get the error: `Missing variables file.`

```
gcloud composer environments run ${COMPOSER_NAME} \
    --location=${COMPOSER_LOCATION} \
    variables -- \
    -i ${VARIABLES_JSON}
```

From looking at [the source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L355) it seems that this happens when an environment variable file doesn't exist at the expected location. Is this because Cloud Composer sets up its variables in a different location so this CLI won't work? I've noticed that there's a `env_var.json` file that's created on the instance's GCS bucket, I realise I can overwrite this file but that doesn't seem like best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like a hack but I copied over the `variables.json` to my Composer's GCS bucket data folder and then it worked.

This is due to [`os.path.exists()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L355) checking the container that Airflow is running on. I chose this approach over overwriting `env_var.json` because I get the variables in Airflow's UI with this method.

Script for anyone interested:

```
COMPOSER_DATA_FOLDER=/home/airflow/gcs/data

COMPOSER_GCS_BUCKET=$(gcloud composer environments describe ${COMPOSER_NAME} --location ${COMPOSER_LOCATION} | grep 'dagGcsPrefix' | grep -Eo "\S+/")

gsutil cp ${ENV_VARIABLES_JSON_FILE} ${COMPOSER_GCS_BUCKET}data

gcloud composer environments run ${COMPOSER_NAME} \
    --location ${COMPOSER_LOCATION} variables -- \
    -i ${COMPOSER_DATA_FOLDER}/variables.json
```